# Why is there a <script> tag in the UserData field in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In the CloudFormation JSON, we have a base64-encoded UserData field containing a what looks like a batch script to me (on Windows at least). But it's surrounded by a `<script></script>`.

This is strange since the format is JSON, not even XML, so what is a XML tag doing there? Is it some legacy thing, or is it mimicking the `<script>` tag in web browsers?

Example:

```
"UserData": {
    "Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
                "<script>\n",
                "cfn-init.exe -v -s MyStack -r MyResource --region us-west-1b\n",
                "</script>\n"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **User Data** field passes information to the Amazon EC2 instance. It could be a password for a database, an IP address for a back-end server or anything you choose.

However, software installed on the standard Windows AMIs also look for:

- `<script>...</script>` -- Anything within those tags will be executed on the Command Line the first time the instance boots
- `<powershell>...</powershell>` -- Anything within those tags will be executed in PowerShell the first time the instance boots

See: [Running Commands on Your Windows Instance at Launch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html)

For Amazon Linux instances, User Data that begins with `#!` will be executed in the shell.

So... **Why is XML inside a string?** It's because the string is simply being passed via User Data to the utility software on the instance and the software is looking for those tags. Without them, the script will not be executed.